# SQL Statement to Rank records depending on specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I currently have the following records:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | postal_code | program_type_id | gender | school_location | school_type |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | 66202       |               2 | female |                 |             |
|  2 | 67487       |               2 | male   | rural           | public      |
|  3 | 68504       |               2 | female | rural           | private     |
|  4 | 67554       |               2 | female | rural           | public      |
|  5 | 67212       |               2 | female | urban           | public      |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I also have the following record:

```
mysql> select id, postal_code, program_type_id, gender, school_location, school_type from applications limit 1 offset 6;
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | postal_code | program_type_id | gender | school_location | school_type |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|  7 | 66202       |               2 | female | urban           | public      |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I will have to match this record `7` to the records in the database in a certain way and  give scores.

Scoring:

Matching postal_code = `1000` points
Matching program_type_id = `490` points
Matching genders = `20` points
Matching `school_type` = 500 points

Now, the records I should retrieve should be in the following order:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | postal_code | program_type_id | gender | school_location | school_type |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | 66202       |               2 | male   |                 |             | 1K points
|  3 | 68504       |               2 | female | rural           | private     | 520 points
|  2 | 67487       |               1 | male   | rural           | public      | 490 points
|  4 | 67554       |               1 | female | rural           | public      | 20 points
|  5 | 67212       |               1 | female | urban           | public      | 20 points
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Take note that 3 overtook 2 because matching program_type_id and gender would garner 520 points and matching just school_type would garner only 500 points. In this case 3 scores higher than 2 in points.

Now, my question is, has anyone have any idea as to how to do this and how can this be done? Btw, this is MySQL 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at case statement in mysql.Your construct will be of following form

```
select <fields that matter>, (case  when tab1.program_type_id = applications.program_type_id then 490 when 
tab1.postal=    applications.postal then 1000 end )from tab1, applications where 
tab1.a = applications.a or tab1.b = applications.b
```

of course you need to change the names of columns in this query to those of yours.

Comment: Analyzing your answer, this might mean that we will have to have a case statement for every combination too. For example, program_type_id and gender would have its own case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function `GET_SCORE(postal_code, table_postal_code,  program_type_id, table_program_type_id ...)`

Inside the function you can compare the past parameters and return calculated score.

After thah just use the function in your `SELECT` passing required parameter and table's fields.

Finally just `ORDER BY` the function result column.

UPDATE

```
DELIMITER $

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GET_SCORE$

CREATE FUNCTION GET_SCORE(
  postal_code VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,
  table_postal_code VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,
  ... all the rest params there)
  RETURNS INT(11) CHARACTER SET utf8
READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER
  BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT(11);
calculate all your comparisons and fill the score value to the result

    RETURN result;
  END$
```

Then just call

```
SELECT GET_SCORE(... pass proper values from necessary tables...) as score

FROM ... the tables...
ORDER BY score;
```

Comment: This is great. Can you elaborate on the function?